# Can OSSEC's active-response handle things at a cluster level?

Tags: load-balancing, cluster, ossec

We are running OSSEC as a client-server model.  *ClientA* & *ClientB* servers are web servers behind a load balancer.  They both send information to a single OSSEC server (*ServerA*), where it invokes an active-response (i.e. dynamic IP blocking) accordingly.

> clientA (OSSEC agent) --> ServerA (OSSEC server)
>
> clientB (OSSEC agent) --> ServerA (OSSEC server)

The active-response feature of OSSEC works great for the most part.  However the problem is that even though clientA & clientB are "clustered," the OSSEC server will block the offending IP of an end-user pertinent to each client.

Meaning, if *ServerA* blocks an end-user IP of 1.2.3.4 on *clientA*, that same action is not reflected on *clientB*.

After reading through the OSSEC manual, I'm pretty sure there isn't a way to address this scenario.  Or is there?

If there isn't, I was seeking advice or suggestions from the community to see if there's an alternative way to handle it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want the active response to be triggered on both clientA and clientB.

If this is the case I would recommend that you take a look at the Active Response documentation.

You can define where the active response is ran:

> **location**
>
> Where the command should be executed. You have four options:
>
> Allowed:
>
> **local**: on the agent that generated the event
>
> **server**: on the OSSEC server
>
> **defined-agent**: on a specific agent (when using this option, you need to set the agent_id to use)
>
> **all**: or everywhere.

source: http://ossec-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/syntax/head_ossec_config.active-response.html